# Populate dropdown from entity framework db context

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I know that there are plenty of similar questions but I couldn't get it working ... I want to populate dropdown list from entity framework entity. I have following entity class:

```
namespace Accounting.Entity
{
    [Table("Cities", Schema = "np")]
    public class Cities
    {
        [Key]
        [XmlElement("Ref")]
        public System.Guid Ref { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class OrderController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult PopulateCitiesDD()
    {

        var list = _repository.All<Cities>().ToList();
        ViewBag.MyCities = new SelectList(list, "Ref", "Description", 0);
        return View();
    }
}
```

What should I use in the view to populate dropdown?

Comment: DropDownListFor is fine

Comment: what is the first param for DropDownListFor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the controller/action code you posted, you could create a dropdown list in your view like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("city", (SelectList)ViewBag.MyCities)
```

Comment: Message=There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'city'.

Comment: Hmm. Just to be sure:  you're setting ViewBag.MyCities in the controller?

Comment: @sidux, You would only ever get that message if `ViewBag.MyCities` is `null` (possibly because in a POST method you return the view but have not reassigned `ViewBag.MyCities` as you did in the GET method)